# Rails 3.2.14 new image not loading locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my local server, I replaced an old image .png file with a new .png file with the exact same name. But when I refresh the page or even restart the server I don't see my changes. However, when I push my code to heroku, I'm able to see the new image. Any clue why?

I'm referencing the image in a link like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("foo_bar.png"), url_for({:controller => "foo", :action => "new"}), :class => "blah" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache in your local browser. I believe you would have done it.

Comment: I cleared the browser's cache and even tried using chrome incognito mode and I still see the old image